# What are the differences between the War Mage and the Sorceress?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

From what I've noticed so far, there seems to be a few differences between the two playable characters in Orcs Must Die! 2.

So far I've noticed that the War Mage has more health, while the Sorceress has more mana, and they both start with different weapons and traps.

Do either of them have exclusive traps or weapons? Do their traps unlock at different times? What are the differences between these two characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the differences I've found so far (all of these are exclusive, so there's no unlocking the starting items of the other character):

- War mage has more health, while Sorceress has more mana
- War mage starts with a shotgun, while Sorceress starts with a staff
- War mage starts with the Tar-trap and Arrow Wall, while Sorceress starts with the Ice Trap and Acid Sprayer.
- Later in the game, War Mage unlocks a hammer while Sorceress unlocks a Polymorph Ring
- The War Mage can purchase the Healing Well while the Sorceress can purchase the Mana Well.
- After beating the game on War Mage difficulty..

> The war mage gains the ability to double-jump, while the Sorceress unlocks "Feather-fall" (gliding).
>  *(These abilities, by the way, have lead me to discover many glitches due to reaching otherwise unreachable areas...)*

Comment: @Mr. Smooth: I was literally *just* about to make that same edit :) thank you!

Comment: I will probably mark this as accepted in a few days. Just want to wait and see if there's anything more unlocked or the like.

Comment: Totally forgot about this question till now. I marked it as accepted though like promised, just a few months late.

Answer (score 2):

Ya.

There are some unlockable items that are not shown in the spellbook. The only way to get them are by playing the game and some game modes such as classics and endless modes. :)

Each class also has unique weapons.

> Polymorph Ring for the Sorceress and the hammer for the Warmage.